# Streaming Mp3 file at specific point

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using this code to stream mp3 file from a web server:

```
app.get('/music', function(req,res){
    var fileId = req.query.id; 
    var file = __dirname + '/music/' + fileId;
    fs.exists(file,function(exists){
        if(exists){
            var rstream = fs.createReadStream(file);
            rstream.pipe(res);
        }
        else{
            res.send("Its a 404");
            res.end();
        }   
    }); 
});
```

It works fine. However, I would like the stream to start at spesefic point (e.g. 00:53).
I have saw a solution by passing a second argument to `createReadStream` telling it from which byte it should start. However, this solution sends the file as chunk of bytes in which the browser is not able to understand it as Mp3 file.

Any other solution?

Comment: _this solution sends the file as chunk of bytes in which the browser is not able to understand it as Mp3 file_ No browser would get it as mp3

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Thanks for comment. Yes I am aware of that.. so I am looking for an alternative solution